# Extract fields from json in Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jsonschema

I am trying to extract only itineraries.element and validatingAirlineCodes and then form a json containing only these two fields in Pyspark

```
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- instantTicketingRequired: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- itineraries: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- lastTicketingDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nonHomogeneous: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- numberOfBookableSeats: long (nullable = true)
 |-- oneWay: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- price: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- pricingOptions: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- travelerPricings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- validatingAirlineCodes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I tried using the df.select() but cant select the fields I want. What should I do ?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and/or what technologies you're using?

Comment: Also, I see that you've included the `jsonschema` tag, but I'm not sure that applies to your question.  JSON Schema is for validating JSON data.  Maybe you meant JSON Path?

Answer (score 0):

Something to bear in mind is that what you are trying to extract (`element`) is an Array of Maps. There is no logical way to extract this without first exploding the array and proceeding to extract element.

Assuming you already have your dataframe stored as `df` you can explode `itineraries` using the below example. This will create a row in your dataframe for each element of your array and should allow you to extract your `element` quite simply thereafter.

```
df.select(explode(df.itineraries))
```

Extra reading for context:

Documentation page on Spark By Examples.
https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/select-columns-from-pyspark-dataframe/

Documentation on explode in pySpark is here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html

Hope this helps!